# I am not able to reflect the contents added in html head of admin panel in view source code in magento 2

Tags: configuration, admin-panel, header, magento2.2.6, script

I have added few script tags in the following path of admin panel:
content->design->configurations->our theme(edit)-> html head->scripts n style sheets.

But it's not reflecting in view page source code. Tried with cache: clean and cache: flush and re indexer command as well.

Comment: check if you have applied on right theme and same is being used on front-end ?

Comment: please attach your screenshot where you add script tags in admin side

Comment: check if you have applied on right theme and same is being used on front-end ? --yes.we have enabled single store mode and pearl theme is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel: `content -> design -> configurations -> our theme(edit) [Only click on attached screenshot image] -> html head->scripts n style sheets`

put your script tags there

run below command

> php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush

[image]